# Making a select option the top option

Tags: php, html

I have a question concerning select forms. I have a variable containing a string extracted from a database, and i want the select form to priority this first, and make it the top of the select form.

```
$smode = "fade";
<select name='smode'>
         <?php
         $modes = array('horizontal', 'vertical', 'fade');
         $i = 0;
         while($i < 3){
             echo "<option value='$modes[$i]'>$modes[$i]</option>";
             $i++;
         }
             ?>
    </select>
```

So when the variable $smode is "fade", i want the fade option-field at the top of the select form, when the variable $smode is "vertical" i want the vertical option-field at the top, and so on.

Hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: add thr in if statement  selected='selected'

Comment: How do you know which one should be selected?  Also, changing the order of your select options generally doesn't make for a good UX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. Just store your output in variables.
Define one for your top and one for the rest.
After your loop, you just output them in your desired order using echo.

```
$smode = "fade";
<select name='smode'>
  <?php
    $modes = array('horizontal', 'vertical', 'fade');
    $i = 0;
    $options = '';
    $topOption= '';
    while($i < 3){
      if($modes[$i] == $smode) {
        $topOption = "<option value='$modes[$i]' selected='selected'>$modes[$i]</option>" 
      } else {
        $options .= "<option value='$modes[$i]'>$modes[$i]</option>";
      }
      $i++;
    }
    echo $topOption . $options;
?>
</select>
```

Also, read up on the [for](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loop.

```
$smode = "fade";
<select name='smode'>
  <?php
    $modes = array('horizontal', 'vertical', 'fade');
    $options = '';
    $topOption= '';
    for($i =0; $i < 3;$i++){
      if($modes[$i] == $smode) {
        $topOption = "<option value='$modes[$i]' selected='selected'>$modes[$i]</option>" 
      } else {
        $options .= "<option value='$modes[$i]'>$modes[$i]</option>";
      }
    }
    echo $topOption . $options;
?>
</select>
```

Or even consider [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
$smode = "fade";
<select name='smode'>
  <?php
    $modes = array('horizontal', 'vertical', 'fade');
    $options = '';
    $topOption= '';
    foreach($modes as $modeItem){
      if($modeItem == $smode) {
        $topOption = "<option value='$modeItem' selected='selected'>$modeItem</option>" 
      } else {
        $options .= "<option value='$modeItem'>$modeItem</option>";
      }
    }
    echo $topOption . $options;
?>
</select>
```

Comment: I'd change `if($modes[$i] == 'fade') {` to `if($modes[$i] == $smode)` {`

Answer (score 0):

This would also be a solution (haven't tested, should work)

```
$smode = "vertical";

function cmp($a, $b) {
    global $smode;
    if ($b == $smode) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}


$modes = array('horizontal', 'vertical', 'fade');
usort($modes, 'cmp');

print_r($modes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple remove the primary item from the array, add it 1st, than add the rest

```
$smode = "fade";
echo "<select name='smode'>";

$modes = array('horizontal', 'vertical', 'fade');

//remove the primary item
$fixedmodes=array_diff($modes, array($smode));
//add the primary select option
echo "<option value='$smode'>$smode</option>";
//add the rest
foreach ($fixedmodes as $val) {
    echo "<option value='$val'>$val</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

This question comes down to array manipulation.

```
$smode = "fade";    
$modes = array('horizontal', 'vertical', 'fade');
//remove the smode term from the array
$modes = array_diff($modes, array($smode) );
// ... and add it to the beginning 
array_unshift($modes, $smode);
```

Working example: https://eval.in/123063

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the following:

```
$modes = array('horizontal', 'vertical', 'fade');

$modes = array_diff( $modes, array($smode) );// create a new array without the top option

array_unshift($modes, $smode);//add the option to first position

//carry on...
```